# Having trouble with Group by and Join EF c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am having trouble converting this T-SQL code into EF C#

```
select 
    se.pcname, count(u.usrid) as total 
from 
    tbusers as u
inner join 
    tbhcontainer as hc on u.hcid = hc.hcid
inner join 
    tbusersettings as se on hc.sid = se.sid
where 
    day(u.created) = 18
group by  
    se.pcname
order by 
    total desc
```

tbusers:

```
Username, PCName, Usrid, Created, HCID
```

tbhcontainer:

```
hcid, sid
```

tbusersettings:

```
sid, pcname
```

EDIT 1:

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(-1).AddHours(-3);
DB_121002_psmainEntities ctx = new DB_121002_psmainEntities();

var res = from r in ctx.tbusers
          join hc in ctx.tbhcontainers on r.hcid equals hc.hcid
          join s in ctx.tbUserSettings on hc.sid equals s.sid
          group s by s.pcname
          where r.created >= yesterday || r.created <= DateTime.Today
          select r;
          return res.Count();
```

It fails on all levels, just don't know how to use group by with joined tables

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] of your attempt so far.

Comment: @mjwills I added an update....but this was my attempt....no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct translation would look more like this:

```
from u in ctx.Users
join hc in ctx.HContainers on u.Hcid equals hc.Hcid
join us in ctx.UserSettings on hc.Sid equals us.Sid
where u.Created.Day == 18
group u.Userid by us.Pcname into g
let total = g.Count()
orderby total descending
select new
{
    pcname = g.Key,
    total,
}
```

If you have additional clauses after the grouping, you need to place the results into another variable (`g`). Then you can access the group key and perform any aggregating function on that group.